# Creating a golden image backed by instance storage and not EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-imagebuilder

I have a golden image pipeline running without problem backed by an EBS volume, but trying to create the same for an instance store backed ami seems to always produce the same error. The issue is that the imagebuilder pipeline continuously attempts to tag a non-existent EBS volume and therefore fails;

Reason for failure:
`You cannot specify tags for EBS volumes if there are no EBS volumes being created by the request.`

The base image is `ami-08d82c356d670cf9c` which has the root device type `INSTANCE-STORE`, and there are no tags applied anywhere in the pipeline (not in the configuration, distribution, recipe or infrastructure). There is little documentation regarding a golden image using instance storage and any attempt to create one results in the same failure.

Does anyone have an idea on where this application of tags is taking place in the process in order to avoid it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with AWS that Image Builder does not support the use of AMIs backed by instance store, as they use `ec2:CreateImage` which does not support it, and also requires the instance to be shut down to create an image.